# Do I have to use OpenQuery to query a MySQL Linked Server from SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm querying a MySQL linked server from SQL Server.

I can query the linked server using OpenQuery as in the following example.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer, 'SELECT * FROM SomeTable')
```

I have tried querying the linked server using a four-part name as in the following example.

```
SELECT * FROM MyLinkedServer.MyDatabase.DBO.SomeTable
```

That returns an error stating that "the provider does not expose the necessary interfaces to use a catalog or schema."

Is there any way to query a linked server without using OpenQuery?

Thanks!

*Update: Per Shredder's answer, the correct syntax is as follows.*

```
SELECT * FROM MyLinkedServer...SomeTable
```

Comment: `EXEC('SELECT * FROM SomeTable') AT MyLinkedServer` - is far better imho because it executes MySQL quite directly and doesn't do weird stuff like OPENQUERY which can lead to strange errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but MS recommends that you use the openquery:

> This method lets SQL Server send the command directly to the linked
>   OLAP provider, without trying to parse it.

You can have a look at the examples [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/218592) under "Linked server examples with four-part names"

Also, I found [this](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;280106):

> If you receive these error messages, a table may be missing in the
>   [Linked DB] schema or you may not have permissions on that table.

I would verify that your mysql db has given access rights to your sql server.