# How to update linked table column from local SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, updates, linked-server

I have a local SQL Server table and a remote linked MySQL table.

I need to pull email addresses from the local table to update the remote.

This T-SQL statement works for a single update:

```
UPDATE openquery(SKYCOMLINK2, 'select tng_id, tng_account, tng_email from user_list where tng_account = 12345 and tng_status = ''A''') 
SET tng_email = 'blah@blah.com';
```

What I want to do is, for every `RemoteTable` record with a status of 'A', I want to pull an email address from a local SQL Server table (example for a single record):

```
select email 
from LocalTable 
where id = 12345
```

So in English: for every active record in `RemoteTable` (could be multiples) look for a corresponding record in `LocalTable` of the same account number (one record per account number) and pull the email address from it to populate the matching records in `RemoteTable`. If it makes it easier, the `LocalTable` can be the driver as below (in quasi SQL-English):

```
update RemoteTable 
set RemoteTable.email = LocalTable.email 
where RemoteTable.accountNum = LocalTable.accountNum 
  and LocalTable.status = 'a' 
  and RemoteTable.status = 'a'
```

How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do a update with join on 4 part names

Comment: I've seen the 4 part names but could never figure out what the fourth part is.  I get as far as SKYCOMLINK2.tng.user_list ... which is linked server.database.table but what is the fourth?

Comment: It is the owner and by default is is dbo

Comment: where does dbo go in the order?

Comment: I you right click the table in SSMS and select create select it will show you.

Comment: I right-clicked it and the only option I have close to what you say is SCRIPT TO LINKED SERVER AS and the SELECT TO option is grayed out.  Also, I tried this:  update SKYCOMLINK2.tng.dbo.user_list set tng_email = 'blah@blah.com' where tng_id = 62873 and I got error: Invalid use of schema or catalog for OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "SKYCOMLINK2". A four-part name was supplied, but the provider does not expose the necessary interfaces to use a catalog or schema.

Comment: Did you look up the error message?  SO is not a code generation service.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81678/discussion-between-xi-vix-and-blam).

Answer (score 0):

If MySQL doesn't have four part names and SQL Server won't accept the reference without one, you might try serverName.databaseName..tableName. Leaving the schema name blank implies the default schema. However, per [this question](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,565891,565891), that may not work with all versions of SQL Server, MySQL, and the ODBC driver.

Here is another question that provides multiple ways of solving the problem: [Do I have to use OpenQuery to query a MySQL Linked Server from SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187234/do-i-have-to-use-openquery-to-query-a-mysql-linked-server-from-sql-server)

Comment: your "someone else found a solution" link doesn't work

Comment: My apologies - you're right. However, searching for it turned up another Stack Overflow question that has both the OpenQuery syntax as well as another syntax using the default identifiers in four-part names (linkedServer...yourTable). You can find it at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187234/do-i-have-to-use-openquery-to-query-a-mysql-linked-server-from-sql-server.

Comment: That was also a question I asked and it didn't have an answer either.